# Android how to check if the intent service is still running or has stopped running

Tags: android, intentservice

I need to know if all intentservices in the queue are "consumed" or the other way is to find out if it is still doing something so that I don't continue until all services have stopped running. Any ideas?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

**Try this may be useful for u**

```
private boolean isMyServiceRunning() {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if ("com.example.MyService".equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: @Kishore this same topic here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176375/android-service-wont-stop