# What happens to an Android app with background services in a multiple user environment?

Tags: android

What happens when I have app A install it in two accounts account-a and account-b?

Assume I am using account-a and start the App (it has a background process).

Now I switch to account-b and start that app under that account.

Questions:

1. What happens to the App which was in account-a?
2. Will account-a app's background service be killed when i switch to account-b?
3. Will both account-a and account-b's background services be alive if i move from account-b to account-a ?

Answer (score 0):

1. It depends on how do you handle the account a with the application. If you are keeping copy the account information in local SQLite db. it's will be saved and you can reuse it anytime.

2 & 3.  Yes if you start the same service again , the running process will be interrupted in middle and  killed. But you can always check whether the current service has completed it task. you can find info in this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7440473/android-how-to-check-if-the-intent-service-is-still-running-or-has-stopped-runni/7441063#7441063)